# Updated partial view model values in contoller after form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-partialview, form-post

In my sample MVC application I have a  model

```
class SampleModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Certification> Certifications { get; set; }
}

class Certification
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CertificationName { get; set; }
    public int DurationInMonths { get; set; }
}
```

My View (I need the certification details to be shown in a partial view)

```
@model SampleApplication.Model.SampleModel
<!-- other code... -->
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveValues","Sample", FormMethod.Post, new { id= "saveForm" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id, new { id = "hdnID" }) 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { id = "txtName" })
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_CertDetails.cshtml", Model.Certifications);}
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Update"  />
}
```

Partial View

```
@model List<SampleApplication.Model.Certification>
<!-- other code... -->
@if (@Model != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Id , new { id = "CId" + i.ToString() })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].CertificationName,new{ id ="CName" + i.ToString() })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].DurationInMonths,new{ id ="CDur" + i.ToString() })
    }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveValues(SampleModel sm)
{
    //Here i am not getting the updated Certification details (in sm)
}
```

How I get the updated values of partial view in my controller after the form post? I am able to get the updated certification values when I am not using partialview.
Is this the right way or should I follow some other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh Nooo... It was my mistake :( . I gave Certification List as my partialview model

```
 @model List<SampleApplication.Model.Certification>
```

But I should use the same model(Main page model) in the partial view also.

```
 @model SampleApp.Models.SampleModel
```

In the partial view the coding will be like

```
        @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Certifications.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Certifications[i].Id, new { id = "CId" + i.ToString() })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Certifications[i].CertificationName, new { id = "CName" + i.ToString() })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Certifications[i].DurationInMonths, new { id = "CDur" + i.ToString() })<br /><br />
        }
```

Now i am getting the updated values in my controller.

Thanks @Chris Pratt for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

If `sm.Certifications` is coming back null, that means that either nothing was posted for that, or the modelbinder was unable to attach the posted data properly.

In your partial, you're defining the fields properly with an indexer, but initially, `Certifications` is a null list, so this code is never actually be run. That means, elsewhere you have some JavaScript logic that is adding new `Certification` fields to the page, dynamically, and my guess is that the field names that JavaScript is generating *do not* follow the indexing convention that the modelbinder expects. All your fields should be in the format of:

```
ListProperty[index].PropertyName
```

So in your case, your JS should be generating names like:

```
Certifications[0].CertificationName
```

In order for the data to be bound properly.

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for the reply ... I added some Certifications values in to the model. These values are getting rendered properly. When i update these values and post the form I am getting the updated "Sample" but "Certifications" in that is null. Is it possible to get those values if i m using the same method?

Comment: Yes, again, if it's null, then nothing is being posted (Make sure you're not doing something silly like using multiple `<form>` elements; everything you want posted back needs to be in the same `<form>`.) - or - the names of the fields are not in the convention the modelbinder understands.